# Is there way to easily calculate the TimeStamp from the current time?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

What I wanted todo is to check if the TimeStamp or DateCreated is greater than 5 minutes, but let say the user return more than an hour, day or a year, is there way to calculate the DateCreated in much shorter than hardcoding and checking the year,month, and etc.?

Comment: Are you referencing https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp-class.html? If so there are mappings between that and DateTime values.

Comment: something like this Timestamp(seconds=1669219200, nanoseconds=547000000) from Firebase which can be converted to DateTime format (2022-11-24 12:12:00.547), is it possible to check if TimeStamp is greater to five minutes? or even a year without hardcoding? by checking in seconds and nanoseconds?

Comment: I tried to answer below, but am not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish here. If the answer is not what you're looking for, can you show the [code of what you tried, and where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [`Timestamp` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp-class.html) from Firestore, you can convert it to a Flutter `DateTime` object by calling `toDate()` on it. You can then for example call the [`difference` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html) to determine the duration between those two `DateTime` objects.

---

The Dart `DateTime` class has many convenience methods, such as the `difference` one I linked. For example, if you want to add 5 minutes to `dateTimeCreated` that'd be:

```
dateTimeCreated.add(Duration(minutes: 5))
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way to validate this if the object is more than five minutes from the current time? something like this (dateTimeCreated.minute + 5 > current.Minute || (dateTimeCreated.hour >= current.hour && dateTimeCreated.minute + 5 > current.Minute)) and so on till a year?

Comment: The Dart `DateTime` class has many convenience methods, such as the `difference` one I linked. For example, if you want to add 5 minutes to `dateTimeCreated` that'd be `dateTimeCreated.add(Duration(minutes: 5))`. If you can't get this to work, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77539096/edit)  to show what you tried.

Comment: is possible todo condition such (dataDatetime!.add(Duration(minutes: 5)) >= currentDateTime) ?

Comment: @JmPlanteras Did you check any of the methods on the [`DateTime` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) and try them? E.g. `isBefore` sounds promising for your needs. Again: if you can't get it to work, edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: AAAAA THANK YOU I WAS SCROLLING FAST THAT I JUMP AND REACH AT OPERATOR